# Atribuir e enviar valor de checkbox desmarcado no Larevel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, checkbox

Tenho um formulário onde o usuário pode ativar ou desativar determinadas opções marcando ou não um `checkbox`.

```
<input name="ppra" type="checkbox" data-oFF-text="INATIVO" value="1"
    data-off-color="danger" data-size="small" data-on-text="ATIVO"
    data-on-color="success" {{ $cliente->ppra == 'ativo' ? 'checked' : '' }}
    onchange="checkStat(this, 'check-ppra');" id="check-ppra">
```

Criei uma função para que quando um `checkbox` for marcado o seu `value` passe a ser **"ativo"** e quando for desmarcado passe a ser **"inativo"**.

```
function checkStat(input, name) {
    if(input.checked == true){
        $("#"+name).val('ativo');
    }else{
        $("#"+name).val('inativo');
    }
}
```

Porém percebi que quando o `checkbox` fica desmarcado ele simplesmente não é enviado no `request`, ele envia o **ppp**, o **pcmso** e ignora o **ppra** que estava como inativo.

Já verifiquei e vi que a função que atribui o `value` para **ativo** ou **inativo** funciona corretamente.

No meu `controller` eu não especifico todos os campos, simsplemente pego tudo e crio o registro.

```
$this->repository->update($request->all(), $id);
```

Com posso resolver isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Bom, resolvi removendo a função para atribuir um valor quando a checkbox está desmarcada e fazendo uma alteração no meu controller:

```
$data = $request->all();

if(!$request->get('ppp')){ $data['ppp'] = 0; }
if(!$request->get('ppra')){ $data['ppra'] = 0; }
if(!$request->get('pcmso')){ $data['pcmso'] = 0; }

$this->repository->update($data, $id);
```

Assim caso ele não receba um valor ele atribui o 0.